How to stop water leaking behind poorly installed 3 piece shower surround
New homeowner here and I am having issues with a shower leaking when water splashes up and onto the corner of the tub where the shower surround meets the tub. There appear to be a few issues - the previous owners (or the installer) left much too large gap between the surround and the tub, over 1/4 in. in most places.

The second issue is visible from the back. There is a plastic access panel in a closet to give access to behind the shower, and it looks like whoever installed it cut the bottom corner of one of the panels for some reason (to get it to fit easier I suppose). I watched while the shower was in use and when the water gets in this corner, it splashes right out of this area.

I know the right thing to do would be to replace the surround and have it properly installed but I am not financially able to do so right now. I am considering either a) flooding some silicone caulk into the corner from both the tub side and the back side. Or b) Spraying some Loctite spray foam sealant on the back side to fill the gap where they cut and slightly down into the corner to prevent the water from splashing up and out.
Do I have any better options here? This is not my forte so any help is appreciated.

As you said the best fix is replacing the surround.  Since that option is off the table you have nothing to lose by caulking.  You even have the ability to open that panel and see if your caulking has worked. Go for it..  I would not spray foam from the back . I will just hide where water could be coming from and create a bigger problem.

I agree with @RMDman. I would recommend caulking the entire length of the gap along all 3 sides, unless you are 100% certain that it is only leaks caused by splashing.
